# Is it possible for me to append a string to a specific line of a file?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm still fairly new to stackoverflow so I apologize if there is anything that I have done incorrectly. I have a csv file that is constantly being updated, but I want to be able to have the option to add a string to the end of a specific line. I have a method that is able to find the line that I want to append the string to, but I am not sure on how to add that string to the end of that line without creating a new line at the bottom of the csv file.

'''

```
QFile listOfStudents("listOfStudents.csv");

QTextStream read(&listOfStudents), write(&listOfStudents;

QStringList studentInformation;

QString junkLine = read.readLine(), line, studentLine,
        appendingString = "Ralph Emerson";

if(!listOfStudents.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QFile::Text))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "title", "not open!");
}

while(!read.atEnd())
{
    line = read.readLine();
    if(line.contains(IDNumber, Qt::CaseSensitive))
    {
        studentLine = line;
        studentLine += ", ";
        studentLine += appendingString;
        line.clear();
        write << studentLine;

        break;
    }
}
```

'''

If studentLine were to be

12345678, Gary Bob, Kennedy Johnson

and I wanted to append the string "Ralph Emerson,"
the expected result would be

12345678, Gary Bob, Kennedy Johnson, Ralph Emerson"

However, the code above will just append the updated studentLine to the bottom of the file, rather than changing the line where it was initially at in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Files are typically consecutive, bounded streams of bytes. Therefore, if you want to write in the middle of one, you will have to move forward all the rest to make space for the new one.

If your files are small enough, a simple solution is to parse them entirely, hold them in memory as a data structure, modify it, and dump it back.

The most performant solution, however, is to write as you are reading the file into a new one, then add the new one as you reach the point of insertion, and then continue copying the rest of the file into the output.